# Disk is displayed distorted in plot

Tags: plotting

What is the problem with my plot? I want to get a disk shape.

```
Plot[Table[-x + k, {k, -2, 2, .1}], {x, -5 ,5}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, (x^2 + y^2) < 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Try reducing the plotting range `{x, -2, 2}` and setting `AspectRatio -> Automatic`.

Comment: @0x4A4D yeah, set (x^2+y^2)<2 will be another right shape, do you know why this happen in the case (x^2+y^2)<1 ?

Comment: I didn't tell you to change the `RegionFunction`. I told you to change the plotting range. You used `{x, -5, 5}` previously.

Comment: Or increase your `PlotPoints`.

Comment: @0x4AD fine, with Silvia's suggestion, I am not so curious about knowing why this happens. --@@--

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug. Here is a test with a single straight line and a `RegionFunction` that differs in its threshold only by `.007`:

```
Table[
 Plot[-x, {x, -5, 5},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, y <= max],
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}},
  Frame -> True,
  Mesh -> True,
  PlotLabel -> max
  ],
 {max, {0.7, 0.707}}]
```

[image: comparison]

Both lines should be visually the same. The mesh points indicate that the function was repeatedly evaluated far outside the allowed region in the second plot, but nevertheless it didn't try to refine the location of the region boundary.

The problem is very sensitive to the choice of region boundary.

To work around it, you can either change the interval of `x` in the `Plot` command to something slightly bigger or smaller than $\pm 5$, or increase the number of `PlotPoints` as Silvia already pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* by default cannot always guess what humans find aesthetic. In your case, it assumes the standard aspect ratio of `1/GoldenRatio`. Specifying a ratio of 1 though is not enough, as the plot ranges are still automatically selected by *Mathematica* to include most of the data (in this case, all). So to plot a correct shape, you have to give both options explicit values, and the aspect ratio must reflect the ratios of the $x$ and $y$ ranges.

```
Plot[Table[-x + k, {k, -2, 2, .1}], {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-2, 2}},
 AspectRatio -> 2/5, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, (x^2 + y^2) < 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Or, for the lazy: `AspectRatio -> Automatic`.

Comment: @0x4A4D True, but I don't find that didactic enough :)

Comment: @0x4A4D and Istvan Zachar - I thougth the main problem is existance of those 2 elongated lines, elliptical shape is obvious. On Your `Plot` strange lines are still there but it can be easily fixed with `PlotPoints` like Sylvia has said.

Comment: @Kuba, that's also why I told the OP to tweak the range of the independent variable. Nobody seems to take my suggestions seriously... :P

Comment: @0x4A4D I think it is because there is no precise question. Some think ellipsis is an issue and others are focusing on those lines.

Comment: @0x4A4D, Kuba: feel free to edit and expand my answer.